# what all elements can have onload property

Tags: javascript, html

Like I can apply onLoad function on body

```
<body onload="javascript:refresh()">
```

In the same way, on what all elements I can apply onload property, As body tag is not there in my jsp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the onload handler in javascript for example:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
       // your onload method here
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than body, you can also use it on <img> elements. See this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 1):

Even if 'body' tag is not there, you can still use the 'onload' event of the 'document' object:

```
window.onload = function() { }
```

The `img` element and some other elements such as `video`, `audio`, `object`, `iframe`, etc. can have the `onload` event.

Comment: What if two pieces of code assign to `window.onload`?